# Run directory has files for imported python packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I'm running a Python script which imports many modules such as glob, time, math, string, shutil, pdb, re, etc. When the script is run, the run directory contains a file for many of the packages imported.

The script is run using Python version 2.7.2 and on linux RH 2.6.

I think this happens when the script is improperly terminated, by a Ctrl-C or some other kill command. I'm not sure that improper termination is the only case when these files are created, as when my colleague runs he gets these files most of the times. His runs are on a solaris machine. Is there a way to prevent the files from being created? If no prevention is possible, how can I clean these files from the script.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is vague.  Give us a list of files being created by the script.  The only thing I can think of (but still doesn't sound likely) is that it generates .pyc or .pyo files in your run directory.  I suggest you give us a link to the script (or a minimal version that has the same behaviour that you can share)

Comment: The files created are named same as the packages above such as glob, time, etc. The script is big and cannot be posted. I created a test script, with import of above packages, and some simple print and sleep statements, but it does not reproduce the file creation issue.

Comment: @Thomas - Under some conditions, I also see the .pyc file left in the run-dir. Any suggestions on why this happens?

Comment: @cppcoder Your report files `glob`, `time` etc being created. Do you mean really a file named "glob" or "time" to be created? Or you mean files like "glob.py", "time.py"? This detail is important.

Comment: The file is called glob or time only. No .py extension. There is some header info. and then lots of hexadecimal numbers and it ends with three lines - %%PageTrailer
%%Trailer
%%EOF